# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graphene_django'

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-django

I have been stuck with this error for a while. Now, I am trying to use Graphene for my graphql Django API but it throws me this error of

`error code`**:**
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graphene_django'`

```
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graphene_django'
```

Here is my environment

Before you judge

```
'pip freeze'


graphene==2.1.8
graphene-django==2.11.0
graphql-core==2.3.2
graphql-relay==2.0.1
gunicorn==20.0.4
```

Comment: Did you add it to the `installed_apps` config under your `settings.py`?

Comment: Yes, problem was my environment, i deleted the old env and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

i think you are importing it as `graphene_django` import it like `import graphene` and once check you are added it in **settings.py** as `'graphene_django'` and if you are facing error after this [docs](https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/installation/)

Answer (score 0):

I figured there was something wrong with my environment, I deleted and it worked fine after.